# Is it possible to embed PHP in Qt (Symbian)?

Tags: php, mysql, qt

Since QT SDK for symbian does not support MySQL driver (spent 5 days trying to create one with no success), is it possible to embed php code in c++/qt ? I.E. I would be able to put in my symbian app php code that will connect to remote db and insert some data into tables ...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "pass", "db");            
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{                                                                   
echo "Failed to connect: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

And after that some insert statement ...

Do you know if it's feasible ?

Comment: You're trying to connect to a remote database from a phone directly?

Comment: yes, I have it all set up, I can do it from my localhost apache server, but can't through the smartphone

Comment: I wouldn't think that's a very usual setup. Exposing a database on the internet isn't, as far as I know, a recommended practice. For what you propose, you'd need a pretty complete PHP + MySQLi driver on the phone. If that doesn't exist, you're out of luck.

Comment: I know that causes big security concerns but how about using Javascript via QT to connect to DB ?

Comment: You can use Qt networking stuff to talk to an application on your server (possibly via HTTP(S), which is very common). That app would talk to the DB (and can be written in anything you want).

Comment: Would it be possible to make it insert data to db automatically ? Without user interaction ?

Comment: Everything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously bad by design - if you don't want to store data locally (you can use SQLite 3 driver for Symbian), you shouldn't have local PHP server on phone, but you should rather have remote PHP server where the database resides and create API to communicate with it from your phone.